# How to get last 9 records but exclude the record with a certain ID using Eloquent?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I am trying to get the 9 most recent images from a user, however, I also would like to exclude the image with an id of $id. What I currently have gets the last 9 images, which might include the image with `id` of `$id`. I would like to somehow not include the image with `id` of `$id` in the result.

```
public function specificImage($id){
    $image = Image::find($id);
    $authorId = $image->user_id;
    $recentImages = Image::where('parent_id', NULL)->where('user_id', $authorId)->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->limit(9)->get();
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use a `WHERE` clause:

```
Image::where('id', '!=', $id)->/* ... */->get()
```

Comment: May I ask what's the difference between where('id', '!=', $id) and whereNotIn('id', [$id])? Both of them work fine.

Comment: `whereNotIn` accepts an array of values to check against the given column.

Comment: WhereNotIn accepts an array, so you can give a ton of ids to "deny". But since you need just one id, just `where !=` is more appropriate

Answer (score 1):

This should work ?

```
$recentImages = Image::where('parent_id', NULL)->where('user_id', $authorId)->whereNotIn('id', [$id])->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->limit(9)->get();
```

Comment: Sadly the query still returns the image with id of $id.

Comment: Lol, didn't notice your answer.

Comment: @AshfaqAhmed, from Help Center: *"you may accept the answer that you believe is the best solution to your problem."* See https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers